# options changes not seen in react chartjs 2

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-chartjs

I have a problem to update the options of a chart in react-chartjs-2, precisely in the dragData plugin of chartjs

I have the dragData activated for the graph, that part works, the graph allows you to drag the data. The problem occurs when I click the button to disable the drag option, the graph does not work, it still allows dragging the values.

apparently in the console the options of the graph change but it is not reflected in the interaction of the graph, I leave the code in the following link.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(props.state === true){
    let ref = chartReference.current.chartInstance;
      ref.options.dragData = false;
      ref.update();
  }else {
    let ref = chartReference.current.chartInstance;
    ref.options.dragData = true;
    ref.update();
  }
}, [props.state])
```

[working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-64jkmy)

Comment: Please copy/paste the relevant code -- the useEffect() hook and the call to the chart component. If they are in the same component, then maybe paste the whole component. But asking folks to decode your entire codebase is a bit much.

Comment: I already modified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [thread](https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2/issues/40) the problem can still exist in this library.

Beside obvious option to shorten code ...

```
useEffect(() => {
  let ref = chartReference.current.chartInstance;
  ref.options.dragData = !props.state;
  ref.update();
}, [props.state])
```

... it looks like you have to somehow force redraw/rerendering.

One of option is to change entire `options` prop passed to `<Line />`. You can use `useState` to keep this config object - of course with moving initial state:

```
const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState(
    {
      onDragEnd: handleDrag,
      dragData: true,
      dragDataRound: 0,
      ...
```

`useEffect` to react on `prop.state` changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setChartOptions(Chart.helpers.configMerge(chartOptions, {
    dragData: !props.state
    })
  );
}, [props.state])
```

`<Line />` chart required changes:

```
  <Line
    ref={chartReference}
    data={data}
    height={30}

    options={chartOptions}

    redraw={true}
  />
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-szsghy?file=components/chart.js)

Of course you can use `props.state` value in initial state... also think about renaming `state` prop, it can be at least missleading ... especially when you'll convert this component to class.

Comment: It's from dependencies ... you can declare it explicitly by `import { Chart } from 'react-chartjs-2';`

Comment: Then import it directly from Chart.js (like https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2/blob/master/src/index.js#L3)  ... source https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: I get error, cannot acces 'handleDrag' before initialization.

Comment: by additional imports? ... remove them ... it should work without that .... you can try to use `window.Chart.helpers...` - it's declared here: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/index.js#L58

Comment: hmmm, something wrong with your config if it works in codesandbox? ... you can try to use other objects deep merging function (instead of `Chart.helpers.configMerge`) - search on SO?